# Rename directory from app [Rails, Carrierwave]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a possibility to rename directory from app?

I'm uploading files via FTP (cause it's a lot of files and it's weight) and naming directory with theme {model.title}-{model.place}. When I change the subject title or place in app, the directory name now is wrong and I must rename it by connecting to FTP. I want to automatically rename this dir when i hit "edit" in my app.

Got app in rails 3.1.3 with carrierwave.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename directories in Ruby with [FileUtils](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/mv)

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mv old_directory_name, new_directory_name
```

You could implement this with a model callback:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Callback triggered by a changed place or title
  before_save :change_directory_names

  private

  # Method that changes directory names
  def change_directory_name
    if self.title_changed?
      title = self.title.changes.flatten.drop(1)
      # Code here to change the directory name
      # Old title: title.first
      # New title: title.last
    elsif self.place_changed?
      place = self.place.changes.flatten.drop(1)
      # Code here to change the directory name
      # Old place: place.first
      # New place: place.last
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would make more sense to name your directories with something that doesn't change. Why not just use Model.id?